# Unbound method error on sphere volume calculation

Tags: python-2.7

I'm totally new to Python, please help me out here.

```
class Sphere(object):

    pi = 3.14

    def __init__(self,radius=1):
        self.radius = radius

    def volume(self):
        return 4.0/3 *radius **3* Sphere.pi


s = Sphere
print 'volume is', s.volume
```

Getting this error : `volume is <unbound method Sphere.volume>`

Comment: `s = Sphere()`, then `print 'volume is', s.volume()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Sphere` object like so:

```
s = Sphere(10) # Create a sphere of radius 10
```

After that, you can call `s.volume()` on the instance of class `Sphere`. Right now, you're operating directly on the class `Sphere`, which, while allowed, does not behave the way you want it to.